# New OS, New problems

Tags: nvidia, fan

I just bought a 'new' Samsung np-x460 equipped with a Core 2 duo with GeForce 9200m GS to try out Ubuntu 15.04 with a fresh install, and was generally happy with it prior to the system updates.

My problems with it so far: NVidia drivers are causing boot up errors so I went back to the Noveau driver; a new Processor Microcode firmware for Intel CPUs is present now and the laptop fan keeps spinning all the time, whereas before it was much more silent.

Are these common symptoms with this OS, my other W7 machines with similarly equipped P-8400 P-8700 don't have these loud fans even the i5 runs much more silent.

Please advise me to any solution overcome these problems.

Thank you, Dom

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that new Nvidia proprietary drivers do not support these old video cards.

Open source "nouveau" drivers do not manage power states well, because Nvidia does not give information on how to do it.

The best solution for this old laptop is to install Ubuntu 14.04 and proprietary nvidia-173 drivers.

But there may be some problems. Now you can download only 14.04.2 with newer graphical stack. And 173 drivers maybe won't install.

So you need to find original 14.04, or downgrade the stack with this command

for 64-bit

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

for 32-bit

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Pilot.  Please excuse my ignorance on the subject, is downgrading the stack needed to install 14.04 or something to be executed within 15.04?

Comment: You need to install 14.04 from scratch. Better find original 14.04.